# javascript object prototype seems broken

Tags: javascript, prototype

I am confused as to why I am getting this error here.  I would like some enlightenment.

```js
function c(me) { this.me = me; }
c.prototype.identify = function() { return "I am " + this.me; };

function d(me) { c.call(this, me); }
d.prototype = Object.create(c.prototype);
d.prototype.speak = function() { return "Hello, " + this.identify() + "." };

var d1 = new d("d1");
var d2 = new d("d2");

console.log(d1.speak());
console.log(d2.speak());

console.log(d.speak()); //returns: TypeError: d.speak is not a function
```

> returns: TypeError: d.speak is not a function

I am explicitly adding a property `speak` to `d.prototype`.  In fact, `d1` and `d2` both have access to the property/function in their prototype hierarchy.  Yet when I attempt to call it on `d`, I get a TypeError.  I have tried various 'tweaks' to no avail.  I tried wrapping various parts in an IIFE in an attempt to rule out any scoping issues, but it had no effect.  I removed the `()` from the last line

```
console.log(d.speak);  //returns: undefined
```

and get `undefined`.  This tells me that `speak` is not a property/function that `d` has access to.  ie. Change `speak` to `blah` and get the same `undefined` logged to console.

```
console.log(d.blah);  //returns: undefined
```

I know I'm missing something small that may be obvious to a new set of eyes.

Comment: `d.speak()` wont work because you have attached the `speak()` function to the prototype object of the `d` function, not the `d` function itself. So, either you need to attach the `speak()` function to `d` itself like `d.speak = function() {}` or call `d.prototype.speak()` to invoke it.

Comment: I wonder what did you expect `d.speak()` to return?

Comment: @Oriol, `Hello, I am undefined.` was my expectation.

Comment: @ppovoski You can use `d.prototype.speak()` to get that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is expected. In most cases, a constructor is not an instance of itself. The constructor defines the methods available on the instances in its `prototype`, but this `prototype` does not appear in the [[Prototype]] chain of the constructor itself.

The reason is simple:

- An object can only have a single [[Prototype]].
- The constructor is a function, so in its [[Prototype]] chain there must be `Function.prototype`. This allows you to call function methods like `call` or `apply` on the constructor.
- Instances must inherit from the `prototype` of the constructor, but not from `Function.prototype` because they are not functions.

Therefore, generally the constructor can't inherit from its `prototype`. There are two built-in exceptions: `Function` and `Object`.

That said, you may choose to get rid of the second or the third invariant above. Then you can make it work, but it's a bad idea because usually people relies on them, and changing the [[Prototype]] has bad performance.

```js
function c(me) { this.me = me; }
c.prototype.identify = function() { return "I am " + this.me; };

function d(me) { c.call(this, me); }
d.prototype = Object.create(c.prototype);
d.prototype.speak = function() { return "Hello, " + this.identify() + "." };
Object.setPrototypeOf(d, d.prototype);

var d1 = new d("d1");
var d2 = new d("d2");

console.log(d1.speak()); // "Hello, I am d1."
console.log(d2.speak()); // "Hello, I am d2."
console.log(d.speak()); // "Hello, I am undefined."

console.log(d.call); // undefined    :(
```

```js
function c(me) { this.me = me; }
c.prototype = Object.create(Function.prototype);
c.prototype.identify = function() { return "I am " + this.me; };

function d(me) { c.call(this, me); }
d.prototype = Object.create(c.prototype);
d.prototype.speak = function() { return "Hello, " + this.identify() + "." };
Object.setPrototypeOf(d, d.prototype);

var d1 = new d("d1");
var d2 = new d("d2");

console.log(d1.speak()); // "Hello, I am d1."
console.log(d2.speak()); // "Hello, I am d2."
console.log(d.speak()); // "Hello, I am undefined."

console.log(d1 instanceof Function); // true    Huh????
```

Comment: +1, but you should add a disclaimer after the "*choose to get rid of the  invariants*" that this is a really bad idea :-)

Answer (score 1):

Your variable `d` is a **constructor** function. Use the `prototype` property on that constructor to access the **prototype object** from which your instances inherit.

```
console.log(d.prototype.speak) //=> [Function]
```

Demo:

```js
function c(me) { this.me = me; }
c.prototype.identify = function() { return "I am " + this.me; };

function d(me) { c.call(this, me); }
d.prototype = Object.create(c.prototype);
d.prototype.speak = function() { return "Hello, " + this.identify() + "." };

var d1 = new d("d1");
var d2 = new d("d2");

console.log(d1.speak());
console.log(d2.speak());

console.log(d.prototype.speak) //=> [Function]
```

Comment: So you are saying that variable `d` used for the function is not that same as the `d` used for the prototype?

Comment: The function `d` was never used for the prototype, only as a constructor. Every function in JavaScript carries its own prototype object; the prototype of both `d1` and `d2` is `d.prototype`. Another way to think about it: every time you call `new d`, what's really happening is `Object.create(d.prototype)`.